# iOS failed to write into plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I wanna write a dictionary like '[NSString:NSDictionary]' into a plist file. But when I call ***-writeToFile:*** it always return me a False. The following is the data in dataDic:

```
Printing description of dataDic:
{
5 =     {
    category = 5;
    img = “img”;
    name = “sport”;
};
1 =     {
    category = 1;
    img = “img”;
    name = “music”;
};
}
```

and the following is my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dataDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary* dict in arr) {
    [dataDic setObject:dict forKey:dict[@"category"]];
}
NSString *plistPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES).firstObject;
NSString *filename=[plistPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];
NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fm createFileAtPath:filename contents:nil attributes:nil];
BOOL boo =  [dataDic writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
```

Comment: you need to format Dictionary in XML Fomat

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
NSDictionary * dataDic = "YOUR_DICTIONARY" 
    NSString *error = nil;
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

if(plistData)
{
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Data saved sucessfully");
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"Data not saved ");;
}
```

please let me know if this worked for you or not ..

Comment: can you please  post Exception Log